# How to know which composer dependencies are needed for a Laravel package?

Tags: laravel, dependencies, composer-php, package

I'm struggling with the needed dependencies when developing a Laravel package.

When setting up a service provider in the package, you would require the `illuminate/support` package. When your package holds console commands, you would require the `illuminate/console` package.

1. What about the global helpers like `storage_path()` or `config()`? I can't find an illuminate package which includes them.
2. Why don't one just require `laravel/framework` for their package? All classes and functions would be available. And it's available in the project anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you require the package to only be used in Laravel projects, it is common to require the `laravel/framework` as a dependency.

But it is almost always a better idea to skip those global helper functions and try to use them with a direct function call. Maybe you can then lower the amount of dependencies you have.

When not directly using the `laravel/framework` as a dependency, make sure that you test the package without installing it in a normal Laravel package. Small unit tests can help with testing the functionality.

I made a "Laravel" package. I also came across this problem. Maybe you can 
take look at it: https://github.com/markwalet/laravel-hashed-route

It only uses the following Laravel specific dependencies:

```
"illuminate/config": "~5.5",
"illuminate/database": "~5.5",
"illuminate/support": "~5.5"
```

Comment: What do  you mean by "direct call"? It would be possible to write `app('config')`, but you'd still use the global function `app()`.
When browsing the [laravel-debugbar repo](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/tree/7a91480cc6e597caed5117a3c5d685f06d35c5a1), there's no `illuminate/console` required, although there's a console command. And it has the nonexistent `illuminate/framework` as dev dependency. Do you know why?

Comment: I mean a function call. Sometimes you can manually construct components (like app) instead of using the helper function. This can help reducing your requirements. As for the laravel-debugbar repo, I don't know why they have it this way. I think Barry forgot to update them and because the repo is almost solely used in laravel projects, the package will work just by luck. I will open some issues on the package. Good call ;)